# CoreData fetch request for count of relation and group by another relation (m2n)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

in my CoreData model I have an n2n relationship modeled using an intermediary entity:

```
Person [1<--] Person2Appointment [-->1] Appointment
```

The `Person2Appointment` entity looks like this:

```
@interface Person2Appointment : NSManagedObject

// attributes
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * participationState;

// relations
@property (nonatomic, retain) Person * person;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Appointment * appointment;
...
@end
```

(both relations are also modeled as reverse relations on the `Person` and `Appointment` entities)

I would like to fetch a count of all past appointments for all persons.

In SQL it would look like:

```
select count(fk_appointment), fk_person 
  from person2appointment t0
  left join appointment t1 on t0.fk_appointment = t1.pk
where t1.date < ...
group by fk_person;
```

I tried using a count-function expression with my fetch-request the following way:

```
 // create a fetch request for the Person2Appointment entity (category method)
NSFetchRequest* fetch = [Person2Appointment fetchRequest];
fetch.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;

// count appointments
NSExpression* countTarget = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath: @"appointment"];
NSExpression* countExp = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"count:" arguments: @[countTarget]];
NSExpressionDescription* countDesc = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc]init];
countDesc.name=@"count";
countDesc.expression = countExp;
countDesc.expressionResultType =  NSDecimalAttributeType;

fetch.propertiesToFetch = @["person", countDesc];
fetch.propertiesToGroupBy = ["person"];

fetch.predicate = ...;
```

After turning on SQL logging it seems that core-data executes the right statement:

```
SELECT t0.ZPERSON, COUNT( t0.ZAPPOINTMENT) 
  FROM ZPERSON2APPOINTMENT t0 
  JOIN ZAPPOINTMENT t1 ON t0.ZAPPOINTMENT = t1.Z_PK 
  WHERE  t1.ZSTARTDATE > ? GROUP BY  t0.ZPERSON
```

But the dictionaries in the result array do not contain a numeric count, but instead, an appointment entity:

```
Printing description of d:
{
    count = "0xd0000000000c0018 <x-coredata://BABCBD2E-05AB-4AA5-AC2B-2777916E4EDF/Appointment/p3>";
    person = "0xd0000000000c0016 <x-coredata://BABCBD2E-05AB-4AA5-AC2B-2777916E4EDF/Person/p3>";
}
```

Is this a bug in core-data?

Am I doing something wrong here?

Or is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: Hi, In my point of view, Your first mistake is you are thinking in SQL mode rather than in Core Data mode. In Core Data you don't need the Person2Appointment entity.(Because Core Data is about Entity(like objects) no about table). You could have and Person Entity what have a to many relationship (call appointments) to the Appointment entity what have the inverse to many relationship personAppointments.

Comment: Nevertheless in order to solve your current problem (according to your current data model), your Person2Appointment would have a (date appointment) or at least Person2Appointment.appointment.date.  The only thing you need to do is fetch all Person2Appointment what its date appoint is past.

Comment: @OnikIV is right, ideally you should remodel your application. Core Data is actually much easier to use than SQLite once you get the hang of it. You don't need intermediary entities.

Comment: Thanks @OnikIV - 1. the post shows a simplified model of my actual one. The relationship itself is also quantified (has a draft/public/approved flag), so removing it is not possible. Besides, AFAIK core-data for iOS is not able to model m2m directly. 2. Is it not an overkill to fetch all the appointments here just in order to count them? In the team-view of my app, I just need the count of the appointments for all team members.

Comment: If you put here your data model (in graph view), It'll be easily to help you.

Comment: Thanks @OnikIV but I am not yet allowed to upload images :(

Comment: Can you put the attributes (properties) of your custom nsmanagedObject ?

Comment: I Guess you mean the m2n entity (Person2Apppointment) - well, it has a "state" attribute of numeric value. But also if it would have been an m2n relationship modeled by core-data directly, I don't see how the aggregate function would have worked...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks to me like a bug in CoreData, but after a bit of experimentation, I think you can achieve what you want by amending the count expression, to count an **attribute** of your `Person2Appointment` entity, rather than counting the `Appointment` relationship (the count should be the same, since the relationship is to-one, unless you have null values?):

```
NSExpression* countTarget = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath: @"participationState"];
NSExpression* countExp = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"count:" arguments: @[countTarget]];
```

If you do have null values to worry about, you can use:

```
NSExpression *countTarget = [NSExpression expressionForEvaluatedObject];
```

Comment: It took me some time to come back to it, but I could validate it now, Yes, changing the target expression to expressionForEvaluatedObject made the trick - thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Im just winging it here but you might find some luck trying a subquery

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(durationMinutes, $a, $a.date < %@)", someDate);
NSInteger count = [managedObjectContext countForEntityForName:@"Person2Appointment" predicate:predicate error:&error];
```

Comment: Thanks @Erik, but I don't need a single count, I need a count for each Person, and yes, I want to get it in a single request, like you would expect from a database. I know how to iterate over all persons and count the appointments for each one, that's not the problem here. I am trying to use an aggregate function with a group by which does not really seem to work on a relation entity...