# Core Data "group by" with object relationship

Tags: objective-c, object, core-data, group-by, relationship

Given are the following to entities with there relationship:
[image: Album <-> Artist relationship]

What I want is the number of *Albums* an *Artist* has. So I want to use group by. But I don't want to iterate over all artists and count there albums.

So I came up with this code:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Album" inManagedObjectContext:objectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSExpressionDescription* ex = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[ex setExpression:[NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"count:(artist)"]];
[ex setName:@"count"];
[ex setExpressionResultType:NSDecimalAttributeType];

[fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:@[ @"artist", ex ]];
[fetchRequest setPropertiesToGroupBy:@[ @"artist" ]];
[fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType ];

id results = [objectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
```

Which returns the following result:

```
<_PFArray 0x7fa1f34c4350>(
{
    artist = "0xd000000000080000 <x-coredata://969B0BFF-9B87-4280-9B41-7920138902FC/Artist/p2>";
    count = "0xd0000000000c0000 <x-coredata://969B0BFF-9B87-4280-9B41-7920138902FC/Artist/p3>";
},
{
    artist = "0xd000000000280000 <x-coredata://969B0BFF-9B87-4280-9B41-7920138902FC/Artist/p10>";
    count = "0xd000000000080000 <x-coredata://969B0BFF-9B87-4280-9B41-7920138902FC/Artist/p2>";
},
{
    artist = "0xd000000000300000 <x-coredata://969B0BFF-9B87-4280-9B41-7920138902FC/Artist/p12>";
    count = "0xd000000000380000 <x-coredata://969B0BFF-9B87-4280-9B41-7920138902FC/Artist/p14>";
},
{
    artist = "0xd000000000400000 <x-coredata://969B0BFF-9B87-4280-9B41-7920138902FC/Artist/p16>";
    count = "0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://969B0BFF-9B87-4280-9B41-7920138902FC/Artist/p1>";
}
)
```

I was expecting something different. When I'm using `releaseYear` instead of `artist` the result is (as expected) like this:

```
<_PFArray 0x7f9f235e91c0>(
{
    count = 2;
    releaseYear = 0;
},
{
    count = 2;
    releaseYear = 1983;
},
{
    count = 1;
    releaseYear = 1984;
},
{
    count = 1;
    releaseYear = 1985;
}
)
```

Does this kind of fetch only work with primitive data types and not with object relations? Any help is appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: Try counting an attribute of the related entity, not the entity itself.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27323977/3985749) for example.  In your case count(artist.name), assuming no Artists have null names.

Comment: Base your count expression on some property – not relationship – like `title`, and use `request.propertiesToFetch = @[@"artist", ex];`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, using `title` solved it. My updated expression looks like the following:

```
NSExpressionDescription* ex = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[ex setExpression:[NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"count:(title)"]];
[ex setName:@"count"];
[ex setExpressionResultType:NSDecimalAttributeType];
```